# add class active to menu in header.php

Tags: class, menu, header

I am trying to add a `class=active` for a menu when the page is accessed by user.

I have this code for my menu:

```
<!-- main nav -->
<div class="header-nav navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="studenti.php">Acasa<i
                class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="noutati.php">Anunturi si Noutati<i
                class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="burse.php">Burse<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="orar.php">Orar<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="cazari.php">Cazari<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

        </li>

        <li><a href="javascript:;">Acces <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Traiectorie scolara</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">IDFR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What is the settings I need to do in order to have the link menu/page when page is visited to be highlighted as active?

I`m using header.php as global header config.

Comment: you need php condition ..

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the page by splitting the end of the url:

```
var url = window.location;
var page = url.split('/');
page = page.slice(-1).pop();
```

Then just detect the condition e.g.

```
if(page == 'burse.php') {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('nav li:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where do i have to put this code exactly? somewhere in header.php or there should be a config.php file? I understand how html works but not so great with php though.... How do i add and what condition exactly? can you please give me the indication for it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry this is a jquery/javascript solution so drop it into the head of the html file within script tags

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it`s working

```
<?php
function active($currect_page){
  $url_array =  explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ;
  $url = end($url_array);  
  if($currect_page == $url){
  echo 'active'; //class name in css 
 } 
}
?>
   <div class="header-nav navbar-collapse collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="class="<?php active('studenti.php');?>><a href="studenti.php">Acasa<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="<?php active('noutati.php');?>"> <a href="noutati.php">Anunturi si Noutati<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="<?php active('burse.php');?>"> <a href="burse.php">Burse<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="<?php active('orar.php');?>"> <a href="orar.php">Orar<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="<?php active('cazari.php');?>"> <a href="cazari.php">Cazari<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        </li>
```

Thank`s for your response!